# PHP regex - capture the remainder of a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to insert some text midway through some HTML content using the following regex:

```
if (preg_match('/(.*<\/a><\/p>)(.*?)/Ui', $content, $match))
        $custom_content = $match[1] . $title . $match[2];
```

The result I want is that `$title` is inserted into the HTML immediately after the first `</a></p>` is encountered. This much is working, however the second capture group always remains empty, regardless of the greedy / ungreedy combinations I use. The result is that the remainder of the content after the `</a></p>` is not appended to the result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother capturing the part you don't care about. Simply replace the first group with itself plus `$title`, eg

```
$custom_content = preg_replace('@(</a></p>)@Ui', '$1' . $title, $content, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically I found the answer 30 seconds after posting this... adding the 's' option to the pattern matches new lines as well:

```
/(.*<\/a><\/p>)(.*?)/Uis
```

Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: In the future, please supply some of the content that you are using as an example. It is very difficult to help you with your problem if we cannot replicate what you are trying to do.